# ¿Cómo puedo capturar el postback para después ejecutar una acción en un dropdownlist con autopostback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dropdownlist

Tengo un dropdownlist con 3 opciones y configurado con autoposback = "true", así que cada vez que elijo un item ejecuta un postback. Lo que yo quiero hacer es una accion despues de ese postback. Por ejemplo: si elijo una opción del dropdownlist se actualiza la clase de unos labels. El problema es que esa acción la realiza antes del postback y después de hacer el postback como que me resetea la clase que actualicé a como estaba al inicio. Si alguien tiene alguna idea sería de mucha ayuda.

```
$("#ddl_Contrato").on("change", function(e) {
  $('#lb_General').removeClass('navBarsActive');
  $('#lb_General').addClass('navBars');
  $('#lb_Control').removeClass('navBars');
  $('#tb_Control').addClass('navBarsActive');
  /*después de hacer esto, hace el postback automático y me resetea las clases 
               de los labels. Es decir es como si no los hubiera actualizado*/
});
```

Comment: postback??? Esto es asp.net?

Comment: Mira si [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888418/autopostback-conflict-with-jquery) te ayuda. Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Estimo que estas ocupando ASP.NET, el tema pasa porque el uso de AJAX en ese framework es pésimo, por eso lo cambiaron y nadie a esta altura debería empezar un proyecto en esa tecnología

Lo que hace ASP.NET es guardar el estado de la página en un input type="hidden", el cual no recuerdo el nombre (__VIEWSTATE ???), pero si vez el código generado en el navegador te darás cuenta cual es, es el que tiene unos glifos que ocupan más de la mitad del código (está en base64).

Cada vez que envías algo al servidor, el servidor toma ese viewstate, hace lo que tiene que hacer, y te lo reenvía.

Entonces tu cada vez que cambias algo por javascript del lado del cliente, no estas cambiando el viewstate, lo que ocasiona que el servidor no se entere del cambio y al recargar el form vuelve a como era orginalmente

La solución es, ir guardando tus propios estados y/o cambiar las cosas luego del postback.

Para esto puedes ocupas estas funciones

```
//esta función se ejecuta al inicio, y añado 2 eventos al postback
$(function () {
    if (typeof(Sys) != 'undefined') {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginPageRequest);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endPageRequest);
    }
});
function beginPageRequest(sender, args) {
    //Esto se ejecuta justo antes de enviar el postback
}

function endPageRequest(sender, args) {
    //Esto se ejecuta cuando vuelve el postback
    if (args.get_error() != undefined && args.get_error().httpStatusCode == '0') {
        //hubo un error
    }
    else {
        //todo bien
       
        //aquí podrías cambiar las clases
        $('#lb_General').removeClass('navBarsActive');
        $('#lb_General').addClass('navBars');
        $('#lb_Control').removeClass('navBars');
        $('#tb_Control').addClass('navBarsActive');
    }
   
}
```

Comment: @Yuseef me parece muy buena la idea, solo tengo una consulta, toda esa lógica funcionará dentro de un evento por ejemplo el change de un dropdownlist? porque ps yo requiero cambiar las clases pero no después de cualquier postback que haga la pagina, sino solo para cuando hace el postback producto de que se elija una opción del dropdownlist.

Comment: @Abel Sinceramente no se la respuesta. Este código lo saqué de un proyecto de hace 10 años. Yo en tu caso haría un console.info(sender) posiblemente este objeto tenga la información del que gatilló el postback (obviamente también hay que buscar en args). Yo lo que hacía era guardar los estados en variables, y cuando se volvía del postback colocaba todo en su lugar.